# Customized Reordering/Sorting of a List in Perl in O(n)

Tags: list, perl, sorting, reference

I am re-ordering a list.

My OrignalList, INPUT: @lineItems

```
[
  {id=> 'id1', ..},
  {id=> 'id2', 'groupId'=>45D,.. },
  {id=> 'id3', 'groupId'=>56A, .. },
  {id=> 'id4', 'groupId'=>45D, 'isParent'=>1 .. },
  {id=> 'id5', ..},
  {id=> 'id6', 'groupId'=>56A, 'isParent'=>1.. },
]
```

In above list, groupId signifies that the item is a part of bundle. GroupId uniquely determines the bundle group. If group Id is not present then its a non bundle item.

Aim - To re-order the list such that all the bundle items should be grouped together with parent item in the starting of every bundle and the incoming order of the bundle and non bundle items (when groupId not present) should remain unchanged.
To sort the list in O(n)

Expected Output:

```
    [
     {id=> 'id1', ..},
     {id=> 'id4', 'groupId'=>45D, 'isParent'=>1 .. },
     {id=> 'id2', 'groupId'=>45D,.. },
     {id=> 'id6', 'groupId'=>56A, 'isParent'=>1.. },
     {id=> 'id3', 'groupId'=>56A, .. },
     {id=> 'id5', ..},
    ]
```

Here my Algo:

1. Create a sortedList of Ids = @sortedLineitemsIds
2. Use sortedIdsList to form the final sorted list

**Code for #1**

```
        my $grouIdToLineItemIdMap;

        foreach my $lineItem (@$lineItems) {
            if(!$lineItem->{'groupID'}) { #non bundle item, add as it is
                push @sortedLineitemsIds, $lineItem->{'id'};
            } else {
                if($lineItem->{'IsParent'} eq 1) {
                    unshift @{$grouIdToLineItemIdMap->{$groupId}}, $lineItem->{'id'};
                } else {
                    push @{$grouIdToLineItemIdMap->{$groupId}}, $lineItem->{'id'};
                }
            }
        }

        push @sortedLineitemsIds, $grouIdToLineItemIdMap; # **[[Question 1]]** This will always add bundle items at the end irrespective of whether it was in starting or end.
```

Now this will yield sortedLineitemsIds =>

```
    $VAR1 = [
     'id1',
     'id5',
     {
      '45D' => [
        'id4:',
        'id2:'
       ],
      '56A' => [
        'id6:',
        'id3:'
      ]
     }
   ];
```

**Code for #2**

```
    foreach my $Id (@sortedLineitemsIds) {
        if(determineIfSingleIdOrMapOfGroupId) { #**[[Question 2]]**
            my $lineItem = grep @lineItems with $Id; #**[[Question 3]]**
            push @sortedLineItems, $lineItem;
        } else {
             my $listOfLineItemsForGroupId = $sortedLineitemsIds->{$Id};
             foreach groupLineItemId (@$listOfLineItemsForGroupId) {
                 my $lineItem = grep @lineItems with groupLineItemId; #**[[Question 3]]**
                 push @sortedLineItems, $lineItem;
             }
        }
    }
```

I have now 3 questions marked above at different places in the code:

1. Question 1 -> Here I dont want to change the incoming order of
   items. Just group them. But what I am doing is it is pushing all the
   lineItems of the group in map, which I am appending at end after the
   loop. How can I can do that in the loop to preserve that order?
2. Question 2 -> How can I determine whether it is a single Id (non
   bundle id) or a groupID (basically a ref containing the
   lineItemIds)?
3. Question 3 -> How can I grep the orginal list based on
   the 'id' and get the corresponding lineItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you don't want to change the order of the items, but that's clearly not true. I'm going to assume you meant this:

> I want to preserve the relative order of items which are either independent or the first of their group.

This can indeed be done in O(N).

We're going to build this:

```perl
my @grouped = (
    [ $lineItem_id1 ],
    [ $lineItem_id4, $lineItem_id2 ],
    [ $lineItem_id6, $lineItem_id3 ],
    [ $lineItem_id5 ],
);
```

To achieve that, we're going to use the following algorithm:

1. For each item,

   1. If the item is independent,

      1. Add it to `@grouped`.
   2. Else,

      1. Lookup if we've encountered the item's group before.
      2. If the item is part of a group we haven't encountered before,

         1. If it's the parent,

            1. Add it to start of the existing group.
         2. Else,

            1. Add it to end of the existing group.
      3. Else,

         1. Create a new group from the item.
         2. Add the new group to `@grouped`.
         3. Add the new group to the lookup hash.

At the end of this, we'll end up with the following:

```perl
my $group_45D = [ $lineItem_id4, $lineItem_id2 ];
my $group_56A = [ $lineItem_id6, $lineItem_id3 ];

my %groups = (
   '45D' => $group_45D,
   '56A' => $group_56A,
);

my @grouped = (
    [ $lineItem_id1 ],
    $group_45D,
    $group_56A,
    [ $lineItem_id5 ],
);
```

Solution:

```perl
my @grouped;
{
   my %groups;
   for my $lineItem (@$lineItems) {
      if ( my $groupId = $lineItem->{groupId} ) {
         if (!$groups{$groupId}) {
            push @grouped, $groups{$groupId} = [];
         }

         if ($lineItem->{isParent}) {
             unshift @{ $groups{$groupId} }, $lineItem;
         } else {
             push @{ $groups{$groupId} }, $lineItem;
         }
      } else {
         push @grouped, [ $lineItem ];
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, we simply need to flatten the list.

```perl
my @ordered = map { @$_ } @grouped;
```

Tested.

Comment: Here you are not making the parentItem of the group as the first item for that group. We need to check if its the parent, then add at front. Like id4 though it comes after in relative order, but since its parent it comes before id2.

Comment: How can we achieve that? Also, you are saying we can do this in one loop itself?

Comment: is 'grouped' variable a map right? Then can we use 'push' operator on it? I see u are using 'grouped' as a map and a list. Not sure if u can do that in perl. Sorry for silly questions, but I am very new to perl.

Comment: Correct. If '% grouped' is a hash, I'm getting error here: push @grouped, $grouped{$groupID} = []; Also, where is %groups used? I am getting confused here.

Comment: Can we please take the discussion on the chat?

Comment: @user2696258, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216578/discussion-between-ikegami-and-user2696258).

Comment: --> the above is not working for a list like this: {Child1Group1, Parent1Group1, Parent2Group2, Child3Group2, Child1Group1} ==> it is sorting like ==> {P1G1, C1G1, P2G2, C3G2, C3G1} ==> but the expexped is the C3G1 should be after C1G1.

Comment: I saw the unflattened map and its looking that this condition is failing: !$groups{$group_id} ==> even when the groupid is present in the map "groups". Can you please help me here??

Comment: It doesn't even compile before of mistyped var names. ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. /// The other problem is that I copied your use of `->{'groupID'}`, but your data would appear to require `->{'groupId'}`. Come on, you should have picked that up yourself. /// Fixed.